# Model unfit for some part of spiral data despite low error

Tags: neural-networks, classification, multilayer-perceptrons

I'm current testing a model for spiral data. After 500 epoches, loss is 0.04 but the result is still unmatch with some part of the training data. (bottom left)

[image]
<sub>(source: [upsieutoc.com](https://www.upsieutoc.com/images/2020/03/08/Clipboarder.2020.03.08.png))</sub>

The model has 2 hidden tanh x 16 units running with ml5.js. I choose tanh because it seems to be smoother than ReLU. Apart from that they're the same.

Is this thing caused by the model or by ml5 itself?

Comment: It must be for ML5. The data work fine in TFJS.